# Sketch.JS On iPad not working

Tags: javascript

How to make sketch.js work on the iPad? I found a workaround, however I don't know what to do with the code the person provided. https://github.com/intridea/sketch.js/issues/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the code provided was CoffeeScript which is basically a more readable version of Javascript which can be converted to normal JS. I used http://js2coffee.org/ to convert the code given.